# How do I force Git to remove a remote file when it says "everything is up to date"?

Tags: git

I ran this command but with the wrong path (back slashes instead of forward slashes)

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached--ignore-unmatch PATH/TO/MY/FILE" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

I then ran this command before realising my mistake

```
git push origin --force --tags
```

Now I've run the first command again with the correct path but when I try to push my changes, Git says everything is up to date. It's removed my file locally but not remotely. How can I force it to update and remove the remote file?

Comment: Can't you push with `--force` again?

Comment: I did try that but no luck. I'm now trying the whole process again after recloning the repo.

Comment: I tried using `push --force` and while it removes the files from the current state of the branch but it does not remove them from historical commits (which is what I'm trying to do as per Git's article: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Comment: @mkrieger1 for some unknown reason, I came back to it the next day and my original command seemed to have worked (maybe Github has some caching going on?) but then I had to run `git push --force` on each of the branches for it to finally work. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `git push` command pushes *commits*, not files.<sup>1</sup>  Note, however, that:

> ```
> git push origin --force --tags
> ```

still obeys your `push.default` setting.  If this is `simple`, then your push pushed your *current branch* and *all tags*, and you probably wanted to push *all branches* as well as all tags.  More precisely, you probably need to convince the other Git repository to update *all* of *its* branch names.<sup>2</sup>

If you had created the appropriate set of branch names locally, before the `git filter-branch ... --all`, then you really just needed a `git push origin --all` (probably also with `--force`).  If not, you'll want to create an appropriate set of branch names locally, re-run the filter-branch command, and run `git push origin --force --all --tags`.  You could even strip out the `refs/original/` names and `git push --force --mirror`, perhaps.

---

<sup>1</sup>Commits *contain* files, and the contained files come along for the ride.  Files that you see *checked out* in some—any—Git repository are not actually *in* the repository; at most, they *came out* of a *commit* that is in the repository.  Think of this, perhaps, as mailing a package full of 3d-printer instructions.  The instructions cannot be changed, but the 3d-printer that *received* the instructions can now print a bunch of 3d goodies.  The objects aren't in the package!  This analogy is full of flaws, but should give you the idea: the *Git repository* doesn't have the *files you work with;* the *files you work with* are *constructed from the instructions in the Git repository*.  A push or fetch simply sends any new sets of instructions around.

<sup>2</sup>Remember that Git *finds* commits using *branch names* (and tag names and other names), and that each Git repository has *its own private branch names*.  The push operation works by:

- finding *commits* and other Git objects that you have, that their repository does not, that they will need to complete the push;
- *sending* all of those objects; and
- *asking or commanding* (regular or forced push respectively) the other Git to set some set of *its* names.

The branch and/or tag names you list in your `git push` command allow your Git to find the appropriate set of new objects that they will need, *and* provide the names that you'll ask *their* Git to set.  You *can* make these two parts independent of each other, if for some reason you want or need to use different branch names in your own repository, but the easy forms of `git push` use the *same name* on both sides, which helps people keep their sanity.  (Who wants to remember things like "my branch `fred` is called `barney` in their repository, while my branch `wilma` is called `superchicken` in theirs", and so on?  Git will *let you do this*, if for some reason you *want* to.  But if you don't really want to, don't.)

Comment: Thank you. For reason, I came back to it the next day and it had mostly worked. I then had to `git push --force` on each individual branch. Thanks for the detailed explanation... I forgot that push refers to commits rather than files!